# Request data in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a view inheriting Django Rest Framework mixins -

```
class ChartQueryView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                generics.GenericAPIView):

queryset = ChartQueryMap.objects.all()
serializer_class = ChartQuerySerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("request inside get", dir(request))
```

The dir of request is printed -

```
['DATA', 'FILES', 'POST', 'QUERY_PARAMS', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_auth', '_authenticate', '_authenticator', '_content_type', '_data', '_default_negotiator', '_files', '_full_data', '_load_data_and_files', '_load_stream', '_not_authenticated', '_parse', '_request', '_stream', '_supports_form_parsing', '_user', 'accepted_media_type', 'accepted_renderer', 'auth', 'authenticators', 'content_type', 'data', 'force_plaintext_errors', 'negotiator', 'parser_context', 'parsers', 'query_params', 'stream', 'successful_authenticator', 'user', 'version', 'versioning_scheme']
```

I cant find the META or COOKIES here. Am I missing something or viewing at wrong place?

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation for DRF's `Request` class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#standard-httprequest-attributes) shows, it extends Django's HttpRequest:

> As REST framework's `Request` extends Django's `HttpRequest`, all the other standard attributes and methods are also available. For example the `request.META` and `request.session` dictionaries are available as normal.
>
> Note that due to implementation reasons the `Request` class does not inherit from `HttpRequest` class, but instead extends the class using composition.

The second paragraph explains why you can't see those attributes by doing `dir()`. The [code itself](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py#L405) shows that an overridden `__getattr__()` method dynamically proxies those attributes to the HttpRequest object.